# Changing the accept-charset attribute in rails form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

The rails form_tag defaults to UTF-8.  I would like to change the form to accept ISO-8859-1.  From what I've read it seems like the following should work:

```
<%= form_tag subscribe_checkout_path, :id => 'checkoutForm' , :'accept-charset' => 'ISO-8859-1' do %>
<% end %>
```

It is not changing the accept-charset.  Is this a problem with rails or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug in Rails. It has [hardcoded UTF-8](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L819) value for it attribute.

So, I recommend to post issue or PR for fix this problem to Rails. Seems like it will be trivial fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can *monkey-patch* the `html_options_for_form` by modifying the `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  private def html_options_for_form(url_for_options, options)
    html_options = super(url_for_options, options)
    html_options["accept-charset"] = "ISO-8859-1"
    html_options
  end

  def utf8_enforcer_tag
    "".html_safe
  end
end
```

I also override the `utf8_enforcer_tag` that returns `<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />` originally.