# Allow form to accept special character for email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, special-characters, simple-form

I want to allow special characters in my form for email.

In my form I have :

```
= f.input :email
```

When I enter `example@geschäft.com`, I got something like `example@xn--geschft-9wa.com` in my controller when i inspect 
`params.require(:contact).permit(contact_attributes)`.

**Resolved:**

I resolved it by disabling html5 on my field:

```
= f.input :email, html5: false
```

Comment: what database do you use? I think, there is not mistake in your form, but your db should accept special character. The clue is you should be editing `encoding: utf8` in your `database.yml`

Comment: Actually not in database; because when i inspect `params.require(:contact).permit(contact_attributes)` in controller i have the email like this `example@xn--geschft-9wa.com`

Comment: Perhaps you have to accept special characters from your form, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48598839/2096740

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer not as an edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved:**

I resolved it by disabling html5 on my field:

```
= f.input :email, html5: false
```